# cloud firestore only add object if its name is unique

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Object1 looks like this { category1: '', category2: '', description: '' }

Category1 has an array field for [category2] and a Name

My firebase contains 3 documents: 1 for object1 1 for Category1 and the last one is not relevant.

In my Ionic application I have made an input field where the user can paste an array of JSON objects. these JSON objects get converted to Object1 and added to the database.

My problem is when category1 is new it should be added to the firebase document for category1 but can't be a duplicate. Or when category2 is new it should update category1.

I think the solution is to make category1 unique Id its property name, so I can check with firebase security rules if it already exists when trying to add it.

Can someone explain to me how to set name as the unique Id of this document or does anyone know a better solution?

in my service:

```
private category1Collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category1>;

private category1s: Observable<Category1[]>;

constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.category1Collection = db.collection<category1>('category1s');
    var docRef = db.collection("category1s").doc("category1s");

    this.category1s= this.category1Collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            })
        })
    )

}
addItem(category1: Category1) {
    return this.category1Collection.add(category1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

changed code in the service to:

```
addItem(category1: Category1) {
    return this.category1Collection.doc(category1.Naam).set(category1);
}
```

and this code in the page.ts:

```
       this.category1Service.getItem(HF.Naam).subscribe(data => {
          if (data != null) {
            console.log(data)
            HF.category2s = data.category2s;
            if (!this.containsCategory2(element.category2, HF.category2s)) {
              HF.category2s.push(element.category2);
              this.category1Service.addItem(HF);
            }
          } else {
            this.category1Service.addItem(HF);
          }
        });


containsCategory2(category2: string, list: string[]) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i] === category2) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

}